# How can I batch delete Facebook Pages' “likes” on my account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

My account was hacked and I am now “liking” 400+ pages. Other than spending a few hours manually removing them from my account, is there a quicker way of removing them all at once?

I don't mind removing any of my own “likes” if it involves doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be the bearer of bad news. Apparently there is not such feature. In their help page about the activities (where you can see a bunch of your "activities") nor in any other aggregator you can do this. Maybe you can mess with the API's as suggest this [question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12225749/792066) you will manage, otherwise, using the web application, keep clicking for hours.

### For the API:

Access to this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes%3Ffields%3Did, generate a token using the button at the top right part of the screen.

[image]

In the user permissions make sure `user_likes` is selected:

[image]

Click "Get", now you will get a bunch of ID's about all your likes, take note of each number, then use the following URL to delete them: `https://graph.facebook.com/ID?method=delete` issue several post request. You can select your preferred application to do it ([using the access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/)) or the Graph API Explorer as I did.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/deleting/

Comment: They seem to have prevented this now as I just get permission errors when doing this.